# Wait to perform function until new data is reflected within the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have `Answer` objects with an `Id` property which is also used for the `Id` tag within the HTML markup inside an ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="answer in question.Answers">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <input type="number" style="width:40px" ng-model="answer.AnswerOrder"/>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="answer-{{answer.Id}}"placeholder="Question Text" ng-model="answer.AnswerText"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"><input type="number" style="width:40px" ng-model="answer.AnswerOrder" disabled/></div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Click to add answer" ng-click="addAnswerToQuestion(question)"/>
</div>
```

When the user clicks the input "Click to add answer" it runs the method `addAnswerToQuestion(question)` which is the following within my controller:

```
var newQuestionCounter = 0;
$scope.addAnswerToQuestion = function (question) {
    newQuestionCounter++;
    question.Answers.push({
        Id: ('n'+newQuestionCounter),
        AnswerText: '',
        IsCorrect: false,
        AnswerOrder: 0,
        QuestionId: question.Id
    });
    document.getElementById('answer-n' + newQuestionCounter).focus();

}
```

The idea is to give the illusion that you are still on the same element but in reality the "Click to add answer" element is not being modified and your focus is just silently switching to the new `Answer`.

The issue is that the `document.getElementById` is getting called before the data-binding and the `ng-repeat` is updated. So the `document.getElementById` is not finding the element.

How do I wait for all the 2-way data binding to complete or is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Maybe some kind of autofocus directive that you can attach to the element in the template?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would rethink the UX before I would do anything like this, but you can accomplish this with the $timeout service.  A rule of thumb is that $timeout will always come after a complete $digest() cycle.

```
$timeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('answer-n' + newQuestionCounter).focus();
}, 1);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/0LnMBv6DqUjFrcmqd0v3